# how to make the tool strip follow the scroll bar

Tags: c#

I created a Form no Visual Studio C# and put a tool strip on top with some buttons like save, undo, delete etc., and added a scroll bar on it to access some textboxes below in the program. I want to make so that when I scroll down, the tool strip follow the screen. What would be the necessary change?

[image]

Comment: C# is not equal to C. I altered the tag.

Comment: I tried to put C # but switched it alone

Comment: One option I can see is to remove the scroll bar on the form level. Put a panel and add a scroll bar only to the content below. There is a property auto scroll for a panel. Set it to true.   Then the toolstrip stays as is.